# Pixel perfect collision of canvas arcs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I have a number of entities on a canvas. I'm checking if the player entity is touching a food entity. The player entity moves according to the user's input and the food entities move randomly and slowly around the screen. Currently I'm doing this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foodPieces.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(foodPieces[i].x - player.x) < (foodPieces[i].radius + player.radius) 
        && Math.abs(foodPieces[i].y - player.y) < (foodPieces[i].radius + player.radius))
    { 
        return true;        
    }
}
```

However, the player usually detects the food entity early, being off by up to 5-10 pixels or so. If it matters, food entity radius is randomized to an extent and the player entity radius increases throughout the game. I'm trying to figure out why collision is being detected early and how I can get it to detect properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically checked for bounding rectangle collision rather than circle collision.

Try maybe to calculate the real distance between the points:

```
var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(foodPieces[i].x - player.x,2)+Math.pow(foodPieces[i].y - player.y,2));
if (dist<(foodPieces[i].radius + player.radius)) return true;
```

This calculates the distance using Pythagoras sentence: C^2 = A^2 + B^2
[image: Why your code break]

Comment: Beat me to it. Perhaps you could explain the real distance a bit more (right triangle and all that jazz) for other viewers?

Comment: Give me a min to draw something.

Comment: This helped me a lot, notice the `Math.abs()` is gone because a squared negative number turns positive. +1